# change colour of touchableOpacity after press but stays

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

Im making a check-in button in react native that darkens after being pressed.
I've read alot of articles but they only explain how to change the colour right after pressing (then it goes back to original colour).
Whereas I want the colour to stay changed.
How would I do that?

Comment: You would need to save the state of the button pressed either in a local storage or in a database.

Comment: Change the color on button press, save that to state and pass the saved data to the style

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a state of isPressed and based on that state, give your touchable different style.

```
  style={isPressed ? firstStyle : secondStyle}
  onPress={()=> setIsPressed(prev=>!prev)}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried: 
const [isPressed, setIsPressed] = useState(false); ... 

<TouchableOpacity style={[{ backgroundColor: isPressed ? 'black' : '#4681F4' }, styles.checkInButton ]} onPress={() => setIsPressed(true)}> 

but its still not changing the cololur after press